# get mysql search results from multiple tables holding different and unrelated information

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working with a client, and keep coming back to this query issue, trying to find a solution, and I've been googling around, but haven't found relevant results.

My client has multiple travel services, things like cruises, beach resorts, hotels, cabins, etc.

I've updated all of the individual search pages, and have been working on getting a combined search page to work.

The tables for the travel services are completely unrelated, and don't share many field names.

On the combined search page, I'm trying to get search results from multiple tables based on a users search term. So that if a user enters "Hawaii" as a search term, they should see results for cruises with Hawaii as a port of call, hotels in Hawaii, beach resorts in Hawaii, etc.

For example here are 3 tables (simplified, there are many other fields on the live site):

Table cuises:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+------+
| id | cruise_name  | destination | price | deck |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+------+
|  1 | royal cruise | Hawaii      | 1000  | 1    |
|  2 | crown cruise | St. Martin  | 1200  | 2    |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+------+
```

Table hotels:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+------+
| id | hotel_name   | location    | price | beds |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+------+
|  1 | sheraton     | Hawaii      | 139   | 2    |
|  2 | meriott      | Florida     | 75    | 2    |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+------+
```

Table resorts:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+-----------+
| id | resort       | location    | price | room_type |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+-----------+
|  1 | sandals      | Jamaica     | 2000  | 3         |
|  2 | dream resort | Hawaii      | 2300  | 1         |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+-----------+
```

As a simple example, say I a users search for "Hawaii", I need to show them results from each of the tables above.

The closest that I've gotten is with a query like this:

```
SELECT  
    cuises.id AS cruise_id, 
    cuises.cruise_name AS cruise_cruise_name, 
    cuises.destination AS cruise_destination, 
    cuises.price AS cruise_price, 
    cuises.deck AS cruise_deck, 

    hotels.id AS hotels_id, 
    hotels.hotel_name AS hotels_hotel_name, 
    hotels.location AS hotels_location, 
    hotels.price AS hotels_price,
    hotels.beds AS hotels_beds,

    resorts.id AS resorts_id, 
    resorts.resort AS resorts_resort, 
    resorts.location AS resorts_location, 
    resorts.price AS resorts_price,
    resorts.room_type AS resorts_room_type

FROM 
    cuises,
    hotels,
    vacation_packages,
    resorts 

WHERE 
    (cuises.cruise_name LIKE '%Hawaii%') OR
    (hotels.hotel_name LIKE '%Hawaii%') OR
    (resorts.resort LIKE '%Hawaii%')
```

The above style query is mixing the results together into rows that contain data from multiple tables, and what I'm looking for are rows containing info from only one tabel per row.

I'd like the psuedo-tabel to look something like this from the query, so that I can easily parse the results in PHP:

```
+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------+
| cruise_id | cruise_cruise_name  | cruise_destination | cruise_price | cruise_deck | hotels_id | hotels_hotel_name   | hotels_location    | hotels_price | hotels_beds | resorts_id | resorts_resort       | resorts_location    | resorts_price | resorts_room_type |
+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------+
|  1        | royal cruise        | Hawaii             | 1000         | 1           |           |                     |                    |              |             |            |                      |                     |               |                   |
|  2        | crown cruise        | St. Martin         | 1200         | 2           |           |                     |                    |              |             |            |                      |                     |               |                   |
|           |                     |                    |              |             |  1        | sheraton            | Hawaii             | 139          | 2           |            |                      |                     |               |                   |
|           |                     |                    |              |             |  2        | meriott             | Florida            | 75           | 2           |            |                      |                     |               |                   |
|           |                     |                    |              |             |           |                     |                    |              |             |  1         | sandals              | Jamaica             | 2000          | 3                 |
|           |                     |                    |              |             |           |                     |                    |              |             |  2         | dream resort         | Hawaii              | 2300          | 1                 |
+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Basically, if I could combine my search results across the multiple tables, where their fields are put together like in the above table, and fields for the resorts are empty in the rows that have info for hotels, etc. I can then easily use LIMIT and OFFSET to paginate the data that's returned, and use PHP to loop through the returned info as an array, and determine the travel service in the row based on the id field that isn't empty to show the info for that row using the proper template.

Is there a way to query multiple tabels, and combine their rows into one result set that doesn't mix up their data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [union query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), this will do individual selects on each of your tables and join all the results into one query. The stipulation with union queries is that all union'd queries must have the same number of columns returned, so you need to `select null as fieldname` from all of the other tables in each subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT  
        cuises.id AS cruise_id, 
        cuises.cruise_name AS cruise_cruise_name, 
        cuises.destination AS cruise_destination, 
        cuises.price AS cruise_price, 
        cuises.deck AS cruise_deck,
        null as hotels_id, null as hotels_hotel_name, null as hotels_location, null as hotels_price, null as hotels_beds,
        null as resorts_id, null as resorts_resort, null as resorts_location, null as resorts_price, null as resorts_room_type
    FROM cruises
    WHERE cruises.cruise_name LIKE '%Hawaii%')

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT
        null as cruise_id, null as cruise_cruise_name, null as cruise_destination, null as cruise_price, null as cruise_deck,
        hotels.id AS hotels_id, 
        hotels.hotel_name AS hotels_hotel_name, 
        hotels.location AS hotels_location, 
        hotels.price AS hotels_price,
        hotels.beds AS hotels_beds
        null as resorts_id, null as resorts_resort, null as resorts_location, null as resorts_price, null as resorts_room_type
    FROM hotels
    WHERE hotels.hotel_name LIKE '%Hawaii%')

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT
        null as cruise_id, null as cruise_cruise_name, null as cruise_destination, null as cruise_price, null as cruise_deck,
        null as hotels_id, null as hotels_hotel_name, null as hotels_location, null as hotels_price, null as hotels_beds,
        resorts.id AS resorts_id, 
        resorts.resort AS resorts_resort, 
        resorts.location AS resorts_location, 
        resorts.price AS resorts_price,
        resorts.room_type AS resorts_room_type
    FROM resorts 
    WHERE resorts.resort LIKE '%Hawaii%')
)
```

From here, you can easily sort, filter and limit your results at the end of this query.

**Note:** I haven't included `vacation_packages` table in this because you aren't selecting anything from it or using it in conditions. To add it, simply add another `UNION ALL` with a new `SELECT` statement

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to use your example to update the query on my dev site. Also, I had copy/pasted in parts of my actual query, and missed the vacation_packages when replacing the table names with example data.

Comment: @rmmoul I forgot the important part - every query must have the same number of columns, you need to specify null values for field aliases that don't exist in each table - I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is doing a cartesian product of the various properties.  You just want a list, so `union all` is the way to go.

The problem is that you have to define all the columns for each subselect.  Yuck.  This requires putting in explicit NULL values.  The following shows the idea for cruises and hotels:

```
SELECT c.id AS cruise_id, c.cruise_name AS cruise_cruise_name, c.destination AS cruise_destination, 
       c.price AS cruise_price, c.deck AS cruise_deck, 
       NULL AS hotels_id, NULL AS hotels_hotel_name, NULL AS hotels_location, 
       NULL AS hotels_price, NULL AS hotels_beds,
       . . .
FROM cruises c
WHERE cuises.cruise_name LIKE '%Hawaii%'
union all
SELECT NULL AS cruise_id, NULLAS cruise_cruise_name, NULL AS cruise_destination, 
       NULL AS cruise_price, NULL AS cruise_deck, 
       h.id AS hotels_id,  h.hotel_name AS hotels_hotel_name, h.location AS hotels_location, 
       h.price AS hotels_price, h.beds AS hotels_beds,
       . . .
FROM hotels h
WHERE hotels.hotel_name LIKE '%Hawaii%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have mysql return 1 row per table like you want..
I could be wrong, but I don't think you really should be wanting your data returned like that.

I would get all the data using `LEFT JOIN` and Alaises, and parse it out in whatever display language your are using.

Here's a fiddle for these tables:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ebd7d/20

Comment: @scrowler's UNION ALL suggestion did the trick, and has also let me push similar fields into a shared alias (so all of the destination info is in under one field name, for example). Pushing some of the feilds into one alias, and giving the resulting table from the UNION a temporary name, I was also able to ORDER BY item_name (which contains the cruise-line name, resort name, etc. depending on the table it was pulled from), and that allows me to show the results mixed together alphabetically, or by price, and such.